# OpenFiler performance tuning best practice for iSCSI Windows file server use

Tags: iscsi, openfiler

I'd like to setup my OpenFiler to host very large files to act as the Backup files repository so mainly the primary use is the Backup servers >2 TB

is there any best practice documentation that i can/should follow in order to achieve reliability and performance ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I've found, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. The biggest Win/Linux problem you'll run into is TCP/IP performance. As of Server 2008, Microsoft really made some big changes in the IP stack for Windows, and it does affect performance from some systems, like Linux. Tuning this is where the major problems lay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty slow, I would hope you have a dedicated NIC for iSCSI traffic, that its not routed, and that jumbo frames and flow control are on the storage device, the switch, and your dedicated iSCSI NIC.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the suggestion, here's the result of the trial, I've made the iSCSI Openfiler 2.3 to talk with my Windows Server 2003 using the same IP address subnet and the following settings in the Openfiler:

R/W Mode: Write-thru
Transfer Mode: blockio

[image]
Benchmark result
it is running very well for file server access so far.

hope this can be helpful resource for you all here.

Cheers,

Albert